# How are library containers in Eclipse accessed/modified by plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write an Eclipse IDE plugin that will add and/or read a library container. My first issue is that I'm not even sure if 'library container' is the correct term. I'm referring to the conveniently unlabeled element for the 'JRE System Library' in this graphic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukwu2.png

Ideally this custom container should function very much like the Maven dependency container. I also expect it to list jars, though these will probably contain a lot of non-Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that could help you, i believe a library is a packageFragment of binary Kind:

```
for( IPackageFragmentRoot packageFragment :  javapproject.getPackageFragmentRoots()){
        if(packageFragment.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_BINARY){
             //PackageFragment is a library (jar)
        }
```

Comment: getPackageFragmentRoots(), much like getChildren() lists out all the jars contained in the library container, but not the container itself.

Comment: Bad to know. Sorry it did not help you.